# Error while running unicorn for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

I am trying to run a Ruby on Rails app with nginx and unicorn. After setting up the unicorn configuration file 'unicorn.rb' when I try and execute this command

```
bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -D
```

It throws the following error:

```
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/unicorn-5.0.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:537:in `working_directory': config_file=config/unicorn.rb would not be accessible in working_directory=/home/vagrant/home (ArgumentError)
from config/unicorn.rb:3:in `reload'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/unicorn-5.0.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:72:in `instance_eval'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/unicorn-5.0.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:72:in `reload'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/unicorn-5.0.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:65:in `initialize'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/unicorn-5.0.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:76:in `new'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/unicorn-5.0.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:76:in `initialize'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/unicorn-5.0.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `new'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/unicorn-5.0.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
master failed to start, check stderr log for details
```

I am running inside an ubuntu-vagrant setup and my app is in the following directory:

```
/home/vagrant/home/my-app
```

And the configuration file(unicorn.rb) is in the following directory:

```
/home/vagrant/home/my-app/config
```

And the file(unicorn.rb) contains the following configurations:

```
working_directory "/home/vagrant/home/"

pid "/home/vagrant/home/temp/pids/unicorn.pid"

stderr_path "/home/vagrant/home/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/home/vagrant/home/log/unicorn.log"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.expertiza.sock"

worker_processes 2

timeout 30
```

I dont understand where I am going wrong. Even the error statement doesnt make much sense. Can someone provide some assistance.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here: did you try `working_directory "/home/vagrant/home/my-app"` instead?

Comment: Yeah jared, I tried that and it worked sometime back. But still not much success with nginx and unicorn. Somehow the app opens up when I type in the IP. But when I try to navigate to another page by clicking on a link it throws up 304 for all the .js files. Still feel, I am missing something in nginx and/or unicorn configuration.